# Jquery UI Datepicker does not work

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I tried everything but the Jquery ui datepicker does not shows up.

Here is my code

HEAD

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="date" name="date"/>

<script>
$( "#date" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

What i am doing wrong.??

Thanks.!

**I JUST DISCOVERED THE PROBLEM:
jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js seems to have a bug because it does not work with jquery-1.7.1.min.js.
I re-downloaded the files from Jquery, they are now:
jquery-1.7.2.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js
Right now the datepicker it is working great.
PD. Do i have delete this question or might be good for others to know this.??
Thanks for yours answers and time.!**

Comment: That code alone seems fine. Do you have other code on your page? Are the paths to your JavaScript and CSS files correct?

Comment: No, just HTML and PHP.. No others javascript code.. All paths are working... That's why i do not understand what i am doing wrong... I tested in Chrome also, and nothing happend...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this code within this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#date').datepicker();    
});
```

Otherwise it will not work. This waits until your DOM has fully loaded before applying the datepicker functionality.

Comment: If the scripts are in the head as the OP says, and the call to instantiate the datepicker comes after the element he calls it on, it should work fine without having to use doc.ready.

Comment: I tried that before posting this question.. It does not work.. I am getting crazy man.!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use **both** the DOM Ready function and the Bootstrap code to avoid conflicts with jQuery:

```
var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
$.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;

$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#date_from').datepicker();
  $('#date_to').datepicker();
});
```

This was the only trick that worked for me, I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You might need the document ready function

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#date').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: If the scripts are in the head as the OP says, and the call to instantiate the datepicker comes after the element he calls it on, it should work fine without having to use doc.ready

Comment: True, was also just a suggestion if the other things didn't work